# Can an <a> tag send a GET request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm building a website in Node.js, Express, and EJS. In the past, I have created forms where the button is of `type="submit"`. I would then have my `index.js` file do a `res.render` to pull up the ejs file I'm trying to route to.

Right now, I'm trying to route from an `<a>` tag to an ejs file called `"/jsonData"`.

I've added the GET request in my index.js file:

```
app.get('/jsonData', (req, res) => {
    res.render('jsonData');
});
```

and I've added the a tag in my home.ejs file:

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="/jsonData">JSON Data</a>
</li>
```

My jsonData file is in my views folder because I set `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` earlier in the `index.js` file.

My home.ejs file runs great when I start the server using `node index.js`, but when I click on the link to go to my `jsonData` page, I get the error:
Cannot GET /jsonData

I'm sure I'm probably doing something obviously wrong but I don't know what to do.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: `<a>`, when clicked (without JS intervention), _only_ makes `GET` requests.

Comment: You'll want to serve `/jsonData.json` directly, which means you don't need to use EJS at all. [Use something like `express.static('/jsonData.json')` for that](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Comment: @Dai I want the information from the JSON file to be on a different HTML file than the home page. Poor HTML file naming, but I want there to be a separate page just to show the data.

Comment: @Dai do you know why I'd be getting that error?

Comment: Make sure your server is up to date.